# Spring integration not able to ignore case while mapping request headers into response

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In my spring integration application , one of the step flows creates an outbound request for which X-JWS-Signature header is added and as part of the response another X-Jws-Signature (see the case difference)header is received with a different value. Ideally, while preparing the response headers as spring integration adds the request headers by default it ignores the existing values for headers present in request and replaces them with the values in response headers if header names are same but it in my case it treats them as two different headers which is not what I expect.

I can not see any functionality within DefaultHttpHeaderMapper class that allows for this case sensitivity in the header mapping to be ignored . Can you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

No; header names are case-sensitive; you would need to write a custom header mapper for this use case.